# datetime milliseconds datagridview cell value to string

Tags: c#, datetime, datagridview, tostring, milliseconds

I have a datagridview in C# that has the dates from a query, I used the format "dd/MM/yyyy h:mm:ss.fff tt", on the datagridview I will see "08/12/2015 11:23:39.343 PM"

However when I try to use this formula

```
MyDate = DateTime.ParseExact(dgv1.Rows[i].Cells[4].Value.ToString(), 
                "dd/MM/yyyy h:mm:ss.fff tt",
                System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

It gives me an error, that the format is not correct, so I used the messagebox to see what's going on,

```
MessageBox.Show(dgv1.Rows[i].Cells[4].Value.ToString());
```

This will show "08/12/2015 11:23:39 PM" showing the data without the milliseconds.

How can I get those milliseconds?

Comment: You use another hidden column for DateTime without formatting

Comment: Do you need milliseconds?  Because this will work with your example:

DateTime.ParseExact("08/12/2015 11:23:39 PM", "dd/MM/yyyy h:mm:ss tt", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)

Comment: I do need the milliseconds

Answer (score 1):

Found it, I'm using:

```
DateTime.ParseExact(
    dgv1.Rows[i].Cells[44].FormattedValue.ToString(),
    "dd/MM/yyyy h:mm:ss.fff tt",
    System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you set the format for the cell?

```
dgv1.Columns[4].DefaultCellStyle.Format ="dd/MM/yyyy h:mm:ss.fff tt"
```